# How to create interface adapter in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to replace client json into my json

client JSON

```
interface Cols {
   displayName: string;
}

 {
  cols:[
   {
    displayName: 'abc';
   }
  ]
 }
```

my JSON

```
interface Cols {
  label: string;
}

{
 cols:[
  {
    label:'z';
  }
 ]
}
```

I want to replace z into abc

Comment: Neither of those are JSON. For the rest, it's unclear what you're asking. Looks like just an array `map()` operation.

Comment: `myCols = cols.map(({displayName}) => ({label: displayName}));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to replace your value directly,

```
const a = {
 cols:[
  {
    label:'z'
  }
 ]
}
a.cols[0].label = 'abc'
```

from client json you wanted to replace with ypu can use:

```
const a = {
 cols:[
  {
    label:'z'
  }
 ]
}
//clients json
const b  = {
  cols:[
   {
    displayName: 'def'
   }
  ]
 }
//for static array
a.cols[0].label = b.cols[0].displayName
```

for more than 1 item in array, you need to put it in a loop or map